# Play Gif with Audio Using Glide Android

Tags: android, audio, gif, android-glide

I am currently using the Glide library to show a gif in my android device, on specific event, but now I also want to set audio as background when the gif is playing, and when it stops the audio also stops!

**Attempt:**

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.somegifFile).into(imageView);

try {
    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
} 
    mp.start();
} catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: audio plays , after gif is going to be completed , or sometimes doesn't play at all

Comment: my question is , how you detect the gif got stopped?

Comment: i don't !!! , that's the problem my friend , but i know GIF and audio both run for 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this 
1. First check weather image view is null or it's not loaded with an image 
2. If its loaded then it means gif starts working .. then start a timer and make it call after every 10 seconds 
3. inside that's `run()` method refresh the audio like you did

```
private void startWaitingTimeRunner() {
        waitingTimer = new Timer();
        waitingTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // reset audio -> stop , release , play gain 
            }
        }, 0, 10000);

    }
```

Comment: there is a synchronization problem , sometimes there is delay between actually gif playing and audio playing , they are not playing together like a video !!

Comment: thats why i asked you to keep a timer and if you know exactly the time that it resets then you reset your audio as well. for synchronization problem you can check whether its loaded or not in the image view , i think it occurs only for the first time and sound can wait till it loads